# How run a jnlp code with lighttpd

Tags: java, configuration, java-web-start, jnlp, lighttpd

I am new to jnlp, I want to use jnlp through lighttpd.

On browser I will do it like this

```
http://10.78.162.14/getLauncher
```

Now this getLauncher must call a jnlp code and download some jar files and run them on my local system.

Problem is I dont know where to write code for this functionality in lighttpd. **Similar kind of functionality is acived in apache by using AddHandler in httpd.conf**.
But how to do it in Lighttpd ??

Comment: *"Now this getLauncher must call a jnlp code.."*  Umm.. OK.  1) Configure the web-app. to return the correct content-type for the JNLP. 2) Include a link to it. 3) ..no, wait.  The first two steps should do it. -- So what's the problem?

Comment: problem is I have to write some C code, In apache httpd we used to write a module, then load that module and then AddHandler in httpd.conf. But in lighttpd we do not have any handler kind of thing. So how all this jnlp and related func will be called.

Comment: and are plugins in lighttpd are same thing as handlers in apache httpd

Answer (score 0):

Update: lighttpd 1.4.59 has [lighttpd mod_ajp13](https://wiki.lighttpd.net/Docs_ModAJP13) so that you can use apache jserv protocol to proxy requests to your backend servlet engine.